# How to get instance of javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo

Tags: java, unit-testing, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, grizzly

Is there any implementation of `javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo` which I can use to create an instance quickly for testing. This interface is long, I just need to test something. I don't want to waste time on whole implementation of this interface.

**UPDATE:** I want to write a unit test for a function similar to this:

```
@GET
@Path("/my_path")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String webserviceRequest(@Context UriInfo uriInfo);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply inject it with the `@Context` annotation, as a field or method parameter.

```
@Path("resource")
public class Resource {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    public Response doSomthing(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    }
}
```

Other than your resource classes, it can also be injected into other providers, like `ContainerRequestContext`, `ContextResolver`, `MessageBodyReader` etc.

#### EDIT

> Actually I want to write a junit test for a function similar to your doSomthing() function.

I didn't pick that up in your post. But a couple options I can think of for unit tests

1. Simply create a stub, implementing only the methods you use.
2. Use a Mocking framework like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), and mock the `UriInfo`. Example

   ```
   @Path("test")
   public class TestResource { 
       public String doSomthing(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){
           return uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString();
       }
   }
   [...]
   @Test
   public void doTest() {
       UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class);
       Mockito.when(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath())
           .thenReturn(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/test"));
       TestResource resource = new TestResource();
       String response = resource.doSomthing(uriInfo);
       Assert.assertEquals("http://localhost:8080/test", response);
   }
   ```

   You'll need to add this dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
       <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

If you want to do an integration test, where the actual UriInfo is injected, you should look into [Jersey Test Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29626225/2587435)

Here's a complete example with the Jersey Test Framework

```
public class ResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @GET
        public Response doSomthing(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
            return Response.ok(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString()).build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String response = target("test").request().get(String.class);
        Assert.assertTrue(response.contains("test"));
    }
}
```

Just add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

It uses an in-memory container, which is the most efficient for small tests. There are other containers with Servlet support if needed. Just see the link I posted above.

Comment: Actually I want to write a junit test for a function similar to your doSomthing() function.

Comment: Ahh I missed that part. You can use a Mocking framework like Mockito, or just create a stub, implementing only the methods you are using. That's the only thing I can think of for a unit test. For an integration test, you could use the Jersey Test Framework, and it will launch the app and be fully functional for the tests (injections included)

Answer (score 0):

You either mock it, or use something like http://arquillian.org/

Answer (score 0):

I was writing integration tests, so cannot use mock stuff

I used some code for jersey tests

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=JerseyTest-master/jersey-tests/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/impl/uri/UriPathHttpRequestTest.java

```
WebApplicationImpl wai = new WebApplicationImpl();
ContainerRequest r = new TestHttpRequestContext(wai,
            "GET", null,
            "/mycontextpath/rest/data", "/mycontextpath/");
UriInfo uriInfo = new WebApplicationContext(wai, r, null);
myresources.setUriInfo(uriInfo);
```

and

```
private static class TestHttpRequestContext extends ContainerRequest {
    public TestHttpRequestContext(
            WebApplication wa,
            String method,
            InputStream entity,
            String completeUri,
            String baseUri) {
        super(wa, method, URI.create(baseUri), URI.create(completeUri), new InBoundHeaders(), entity);
    }
}
```

If you get any errors about request scope beans see [request scoped beans in spring testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411343/request-scoped-beans-in-spring-testing)