# JAX-RS (Jersey) webapp in embedded tomcat works in IDE but not as JAR

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I am building a jersey webapp and I am using embedded tomcat for portability. It's quite simple with a single resource. The problem I am experiencing is that when I run the webapp through the IDE (intellij), everything works fine and I see my class extending `ResourceConfig` being initialised. It also responds to HTTP request. It works with the IDE both using Gradle and the internal build tools

However, as soon as I build it with gradle through the command line, using the shadowJar plugin, nothing is loaded in tomcat. I see it spinning up, but none of the log lines are appearing and all my HTTP requests result in 404. I'm not sure how to debug this.

My Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }

    public void start() {

        String port = System.getProperty("port");
        if (port == null) {
            port = "8442";
        }

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
        tomcat.getConnector();

        String absolutePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/webapp", absolutePath);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

My `MyApplication` class

```
@ApplicationPath("app")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        setApplicationName("My web app");
        LOG.info("Hello!")
        packages("com.xxx.xxx.xxx.resources");
    }
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree(dir: '../libs/shadow/', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
mainClassName = 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Main'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

dependencies {
    implementation libraries.javax_servlet
    implementation libraries.args4j
    implementation libraries.log4j2
    implementation libraries.common_loggings
    implementation libraries.jersey
    implementation libraries.tomcat

    implementation project(":common")

}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Main')
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you will have to create a Jersey Servlet and add it to the Tomcat container. You would create an instance of Jersey's ServletContainer passing in your ResourceConfig to the constructor.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I've tried that too, I can't seem to understand why in the IDE everything is fine and with gradle through CLI it is not. Any way to see how the IDE is building the project?

Comment: Have a look at the bottom code block in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222254/2587435). Look specifically in the @Before setup method